# Consulta e exibição de um atributo NOME de outra tabela com Inner Join e Java

Tags: java, html, mysql, eclipse, servlet

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com uma duvida aqui com a consulta entre duas tabelas e posterior exibição em página HTML. A verdade é que estou com duas classes em JAVA, uma chamada Clientes e outra de Vendedores. Na criação da classe model "Clientes" coloquei um atributo chamado vendedor_id para relacionar as duas tabelas. Veja abaixo pequeno trecho do codigo.

```
public class Cliente{
    
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String cidade; 
    private String nota;
    private int id_vendedor;
```

A outra classe seria:

```
public class Vendedor {
    
    
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String cidade; 
    private Double comissao;
```

No intuito de relacionar as duas tabelas (Clientes e Vendedores) e exibir em uma página HTML eu digitei o Seguinte código no DAO do Java.

```
    public static List<Clientes> find(String pesquisa){
        
        
        sql = String.format("SELECT cliente.cliente_id, cliente.cust_name, cliente.city, cliente.grade,**cliente.vendedor_id**  FROM cliente INNER JOIN vendedor ON cliente.vendedor_id = vendedor.vendedor_id WHERE cliente_name like '%s%%' OR cliente_id LIKE '%s%%' ", pesquisa, pesquisa);

            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);  try {
            
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

O codigo que segue depois do código acima, percorreria esse ResultSet e colocaria todos os resultados, um por um como objetos do meu model cliente. Entretanto na hora de exibir no HTML eu tenho o objeto cliente com um codigo vendedor apenas, mas eu queria exibir não apenas o código mas o nome do vendedor.

O codigo a seguir pertence à minha página HTML para resgatar esse ResultSet(mas apenas o codigo do vendedor pois meu model clientes como ja disse tem apenas o cod_vendedor).

```
<c:forEach items="${clientes}" var="cliente">
        <tr>
            <td>${cliente.id}</td>
            <td>${cliente.nome}</td>
            <td>${cliente.cidade}</td>
            <td>${cliente.nota}</td>
            <td>${cliente.vendedor}</td>
            <td>
            <a href="CustomerDelete?customerId=${customer.id}">deletar</a>
            <a href="CustomerUpdate?customerId=${customer.id}">atualizar</a>
                        
            </td>
        
        </tr>
```

Será que devo criar outro campo com o nome do vendedor dentro da tabela de clientes? Isso seria muito esstranho. Se vocês puderem me ajudar eu serei muito grato a vocês. Isso é um projeto final para concluir meu semetre em uma materia da faculdade. É extremamente importante pra mim. Muito obgdo desde ja.

Answer (score -2):

- É uma boa prática criar suas classes que possuem relacionamento desta
  forma ou criar inner class:

  public class Vendedor {

  ```
   private int id;
   private String nome;
   private String cidade; 
   private Double comissao;
   ....
  ```

  public class Cliente{

  ```
   private int id;
   private String nome;
   private String cidade; 
   private String nota;
   private Vendedor vendedor;
   ....
  ```
- Sobre o sql você pode adicionar alias aos campos e retornar o que for
  preciso exemplo:

  SELECT cliente.id  as cliente_id,
  cliente.nome as cliente_nome,
  cliente.cidade as cliente_cidade,
  cliente.nota as cliente_nota,
  vendedor.id as vendedor_id,
  vendedor.nome as vendedor_nome,
  vendedor.cidade as vendedor_cidade,
  vendedor.comissao as vendedor_comissao
  FROM cliente INNER JOIN vendedor ON cliente.vendedor_id = vendedor.id WHERE
  cliente.nome like '%%s%' OR cliente.id LIKE '%%s%';
- Agora em relação ao ResultSet.  você pode criar instancias dos
  objetos necessários para retornar para o seu html:

  ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

  ```
   ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList();

   while (resultSet.next()) {
       Vendedor vendedor = new Vendedor();
       vendedor.setId(resultSet.getInt("vendedor_id"))
       vendedor.setNome(resultSet.getString("vendedor_nome"))
       vendedor.setCidade(resultSet.getString("vendedor_cidade"))
       vendedor.setComissao(resultSet.getDouble("vendedor_comissao"))

       Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
       cliente.setVendedor(vendedor);
       .....

       clientes.add(cliente);
   }

   return clientes;
  ```

Comment: Paulo., muito obrigado pelo seu retorno , foi Majestoso, ainda vou testar mas bateu exatamente com a idéia que eu tinha em mente, se era uma boa prática ou não fazer o que eu estava fazendo , resumindoi estava adotando metodo nao muito legal. Agradeço demais por sua resposta. Obrigado

Answer (score -3):

Boa! Me parece um problema de SQL, se eu entendi bem seria listar os nomes dos vendedores atrelados ao id_vendedor na tabela de clientes? Se entendi certo, basta fazer uma consulta que retorne os vendedores associados aos clientes.

```
select c.cliente_id, c.cliente_name, c.vendedor_id, (select 
v.vendedor_nome from vendedor v WHERE v.vendedor_id = c.vendedor_id) as 
cliente_vendedor_nome from cliente c
```

Os nomes dos campos ficaram diferentes do seu exemplo, mas você pode ajustar. Uma outra forma de resolver isso seria fazendo as consultas de forma individual e ir tratando dentro da aplicação, mas resolvendo no SQL já ganha um tempo...

Espero que seja isso!